# Having trouble implementing JUnit tests

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

So I am working on using JUnit test cases in Eclipse and I am getting an error with my constructor that says "Default constructor cannot handle exception type InvalidArgException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor".

I'll include everything that I have so far, but I am stuck here and not really sure what to do now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

This is the test class

```
package test;

    import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


    import Main.Contact;

    class ContactTest {



Contact contact = new Contact("13579", "Garrett", "Strang", "1234567890", "2468 Washington Avenue");

@Test
void getContactID() {
    assertEquals("13579", contact.getContactID());
}

@Test
void getFirstname() {
    assertEquals("Garrett", contact.getFirstName());
}

@Test
void getLastName() {
    assertEquals("Strang", contact.getLastName());
}

@Test
void getPhoneNumber() {
    assertEquals("1234567890", contact.getPhoneNumber());
}

@Test
void getAddress() {
    assertEquals("2468 Washington Avenue", contact.getAddress());
}
```

}

The Contact Class:

```
public class Contact {

//declare private contact objects
private String contactID;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String phoneNum;
private String address;


//Ensure invalid objects are caught  

public Contact(String cID, String fN, String lN, String pN, String addr) throws InvalidArgException {
    
    //contact ID string cannot be longer than 10 characters. The contact ID shall not be null and shall not be updatable.
    if (cID == null || cID.length() > 10) {
        throw new InvalidArgException("CONTACT ID IS INVALID");
    }
    if (fN == null || fN.length() > 10) {
        throw new InvalidArgException("FIRST NAME IS INVALID");
    }
    if (lN == null || lN.length() > 10) {
        throw new InvalidArgException("LAST NAME IS INVALID");
    }
    if (pN == null || pN.length() > 10) {
        throw new InvalidArgException("PHONE NUMBER IS INVALID");
    }
    if (addr == null || addr.length() > 10) {
        throw new InvalidArgException("ADDRESS IS INVALID");
    }   
    
    
}
```

The InvalidArgExcetion class:

```
package Main;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class InvalidArgException extends Exception {

public InvalidArgException(String string) {
    super(string);
    System.out.println(string + "IS AN INVALID ARGUMENT");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The construction of `Contact` may throw a checked exception, `InvalidArgException`.

Because the construction of `ContactTest` involves creating a `Contact` instance, that may also throw an `InvalidArgException`, but `ContactTest` does not declare this.

You need to add a constructor to `ContactTest`:

```
...
public ContactTest() throws InvalidArgException {
}
...
```

(I'm not sure why your example refers to super constructors. In my JDK I just get `java: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown`)